# Request SQL when table contains attributes composed by several words separated by point.

Tags: mysql

For a projet, I retrieved the database from a client. This database contains tables that have attributes composed by several words that are concatenated separated by a point. exemple :

```
table A : id, number.client , global.score
table B : id, favorite.style
```

So when I do a sql request on this tables to filter to filter the results according to `number.client` for exemple, I have an error returned by MySQL.

For exemple I have this request :

```
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
ON (A.ref_track = B.id) 
INNER JOIN C 
ON (C.id = B.ref_plannode) 
WHERE (B.id= 1) 
AND (A.number.client > 50) 
ORDER BY A.id DESC
```

When I run this request I get this error :

```
MySQL replied:  
#1064 - Syntax error on A.number.client > 50
```

I think that MySql don't failed when we have an attribute composed by servel words separated by point ( like number.client). So what is the solution ??

For inforamtion this database is out of my responsibility, I got it from a client!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to quote the columns names with "`"

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A 
JOIN    B 
ON      A.ref_track = B.id
JOIN    C
ON      C.id = B.ref_plannode
WHERE   B.id= 1
        AND A.`number.client` > 50
ORDER BY A.id DESC
```

**Edit**

[Working example](http://rextester.com/NGCVM90003)

Answer (score 1):

Is the same case that white spaces, you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM A 
INNER JOIN B 
ON (A.ref_track = B.id) 
INNER JOIN C 
ON (C.id = B.ref_plannode) 
WHERE (B.id= 1) 
AND (A.`number.client` > 50) 
ORDER BY A.id DESC
```

The MySQL can use diferent quotes or braquets, depends of configuration.
The MySQL server can operate in different SQL modes, and can apply these modes differently for different clients, depending on the value of the sql_mode system variable.
You can view the configuration with this command:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

And you can know more about the configuration of mysql here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote the column name putting it between square brackets.
So

```
AND (A.[number.client] > 50)
```